# How to set default connection string in ASP.NET Web API controller dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI service set up, initially it was only set up with a single connection string so was defaulting to this single connection to retrieve the data from.

I have now added a second connection string to the web.config and wanted to know how a user can pass the name of the connection to be used when making a call in order for the service to point to the selected database. At the moment it will only point to the first connection string in the file.

I have seen some solutions where a string variable is being set using the configuration manager and being passed down to the Data access layer, but what I am after is a way to not have to pass down an extra variable and for the API to set the selected connection string as the default and for it to point to that db automatically, similar to if there was only one connection string.

Comment: So users should select a connection before doing any DB querying? Is that correct? And each user could select a different connection... Simultaneously?

Comment: Yes that's correct, it is for internal use only and requires regular access to a single database but semi frequent access to other databases

Comment: Why not expose another method that you control the connection string used within the code for that method

Comment: the DALs are basically pre-existing code from the main local application, they use the "sessionID" from the logged in user to automatically set the connection string for the SQL database. I am not permitted to make changes to the pre existing code so I need to be able to point to a different database within the controller instead.

Comment: The new method would be on the controller, so no DAL changes required.

Comment: sorry do you mean writing a method in the controller that makes the call to the DB directly?

Comment: No, I mean add a new method to the controller that calls the existing DAL functionality. Obviously, the DAL is already loosely coupled and has no interaction with the UI layer, so you must be passing in data for it to make the decision about which connection string to use.